# Android Studio Imageview source

Tags: android

Where should i put my picture to find ot as a valid source. What type of file type should it be? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking where you should store pictures on the device?

Comment: Im wondering where in my android studio i shoild put the image for my imageview in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store images under `res/drawable` folder of your package as a `.png` file. Then you should be able to do

```
mImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name));
```

to get the image.